# Python: Trouble with Nested loops. Want to run random variable multiple times and averaging results...

Tags: python, while-loop, nested, nested-loops

I tried to use a while loop inside a while loop but have had little success. We want to select a number from the deck variable. The selection variable will go up each time a number between 1 and 20 are selected.

We then want to run that piece 100 times and average the type1 variable. The end result should be a number between 1 and 7. Any help would be fantastic!

```
import random
deck = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60]

a = 0
b = 0
type1 = 0

while b < 100:
    while a < 7:
        a += 1
        selection = deck[random.randint(0,len(deck)-1)]
        if selection > 0 and selection < 21:
            print "success!"
            type1 += 1
        print type1
b += 1
print b

exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Few minor problems, see the comments.

```
import random
# Use a list comprehension to make it more readable
deck = [x for x in range(1, 61)]
# Consider creating a length variable, so you aren't calculating len(deck) every loop
deck_length = len(deck)

a = 0
b = 0
type1 = 0

while b < 100:
    while a < 7:
        a += 1
        selection = deck[random.randint(0,deck_length-1)]
        if selection > 0 and selection < 21:
            print("success!")
            type1 += 1
        print type1
    # Move this increment into the while loop, so that it gets updated.
    b += 1
    print b

exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a functional version:

```
from random import choice

DECK  = list(range(1, 61))

def get_hand(num_cards = 7):
    return [choice(DECK) for _ in range(num_cards)]

def eval_hand(hand):
    return sum(card <= 20 for card in hand)

def average(iterable):
    lst = list(iterable)
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)

def get_avg_hand(num_hands=100):
    return average(eval_hand(get_hand()) for _ in range(num_hands))

avg = get_avg_hand()
```

but it still disguises the underlying math, which simplifies to:

> Given 700 integers chosen uniformly from [1..60],
>   how many do you expect to be <= 20?

which gives a probability distribution like

```
from math import factorial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SAMPLES    = 700
TRUE_ODDS  = float(20) / 60
FALSE_ODDS = 1. - TRUE_ODDS

def odds(x):
    """
    Return the probability that exactly x samples are true
    """
    return (
        # number of possible arrangements
        factorial(SAMPLES) / (factorial(x) * factorial(SAMPLES - x))
        # odds of each arrangement
        * TRUE_ODDS ** x * FALSE_ODDS ** (SAMPLES - x)
    )

# domain
xs = list(range(SAMPLES + 1))
# range
ys = [odds(x) for x in xs]

plt.plot(xs, ys)
```

which looks like

[image]